# "ominus" as plotmark in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following scatter plot:

[image]

I would like to know how to make some points an `oplus` - which works, and some other points an `ominus` - which does not work.

In the below `tex` code I can replace:

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=8pt, thin, color = blue]
```

With:

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=oplus, mark size=8pt, thin, color = blue]
```

Which works (I changed `+` with `oplus`) and gives me the following output:

[image]

However, when I want to change the `-` to an `ominus` the same does not work.

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=-, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
```

Works, but:

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=ominus, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
```

Does not.

I have tried defining the uni-code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2296}{\anchor} # minus with circle
```

But cannot get it working.

LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}

\begin{document}


% plot 1: base plot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40]
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    %xlabel=$A$,
    %ylabel=$B$,
    ticks=none,
  ]

    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=8pt, thin, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
    }; %\label{plot_one}
    \addplot[only marks, mark=-, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)
      (0.90, 0.15)
    }; 
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

EDIT:

When I apply the `mark = halfcircle` I get some white space added to my plot when I colour the backgrouds. How can I colour them the same as the background?

[image]

New tex:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}

\begin{document}


% plot 1: base plot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40]
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    %xlabel=$A$,
    %ylabel=$B$,
    ticks=none,
  ]

    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=8pt, thin, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
    }; %\label{plot_one}
    \addplot[only marks, mark=halfcircle, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)
      (0.90, 0.15)
    }; 
    
        \path[name path = begin_left_shade_path_4] (axis cs:1.0, 0.7) -- (axis cs:0.0, 0.7);
    \path[name path = end_left_shade_path_4] (axis cs:1.0, 0.0) -- (axis cs:0.0, 0.0);
    \addplot [bubblegum] fill between[of = begin_left_shade_path_4 and end_left_shade_path_4, soft clip = {domain=0.0:0.95}];
    
    \path[name path = begin_left_shade_path_2] (axis cs:0.0, 1.0) -- (axis cs:1.0, 1.0);
    \path[name path = end_left_shade_path_2] (axis cs:0.0, 0.70) -- (axis cs:1.0, 0.70);
    \addplot [babyblue] fill between[of = begin_left_shade_path_2 and end_left_shade_path_2, soft clip = {domain=0.0:0.95}];
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `mark=halfcircle`.

Comment: 2 days I spent on that problem... Thank you very much for solving it for me! :)

Comment: I added an update.

Comment: If you want to use something ready-made, you can use circle split from the shapes library.  See new answer.

Comment: What an ominous question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the PGFPlots manual about marks, you will not find the ominous `ominus` mark. For `halfcircle` p. 184:

> mark=halfcircle
>
> One half is filled with white (more precisely, with
> mark color).

So you can just change `mark color` to the same as the background:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\definecolor{babyblue}{rgb}{0.54, 0.81, 0.94}
\definecolor{bubblegum}{rgb}{0.99, 0.76, 0.8}

\begin{document}
% plot 1: base plot
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.40]
  \pgfplotsset{
      scale only axis,
  }
  \begin{axis}[
    %xlabel=$A$,
    %ylabel=$B$,
    ticks=none,
  ]

    \addplot[only marks, mark=+, mark size=8pt, thin, color = blue]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
    }; %\label{plot_one}
    \addplot[only marks, mark=halfcircle, mark color=bubblegum, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.15)
    }; 
    \addplot[only marks, mark=halfcircle, mark color=babyblue, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
    coordinates{ % + data
      (0.90, 0.85)
    }; 
 
     \path[name path = begin_left_shade_path_4] (axis cs:1.0, 0.7) -- (axis cs:0.0, 0.7);
    \path[name path = end_left_shade_path_4] (axis cs:1.0, 0.0) -- (axis cs:0.0, 0.0);
    \addplot [bubblegum] fill between[of = begin_left_shade_path_4 and end_left_shade_path_4, soft clip = {domain=0.0:0.95}];
    
    \path[name path = begin_left_shade_path_2] (axis cs:0.0, 1.0) -- (axis cs:1.0, 1.0);
    \path[name path = end_left_shade_path_2] (axis cs:0.0, 0.70) -- (axis cs:1.0, 0.70);
    \addplot [babyblue] fill between[of = begin_left_shade_path_2 and end_left_shade_path_2, soft clip = {domain=0.0:0.95}];
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot with plus/minus symbols]

**Edit:**
In the TikZ manual, I found this:

> The special value none disables filling of the respective parts.

So you can use:

```
\addplot[only marks, mark=halfcircle, mark color=none, mark size=8pt, thin, color = red]
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there is no "ominus-mark" you could create the marks by yourself:

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus}{....}
```

**1a. New.** If you want to use something ready-made, you can use `circle split` from the `shapes` library.

*Note that the other possibility `mark=halfcircle`, because of "One half is filled with white", is not really suitable for a fillable "ominus"*

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus}{
\node[shape=circle split, 
draw,   fill,    minimum size=2*\pgfplotmarksize, inner sep=0pt,
]{};
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}% <---

\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus}{
\node[shape=circle split, 
draw,   fill,  
minimum size=2*\pgfplotmarksize, inner sep=0pt,
]{};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
only marks, 
mark size=5pt 
]
\addplot+[mark=oplus*, mark options={fill=cyan!55}] coordinates { 
     (0.20,0.05) %
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)  
};
\addplot+[red, mark=myominus, mark options={fill=pink} ] coordinates { 
     (0.20,0.05) % 
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**1b.** Because you changed your question, while processing and I do not really know, what you want to create.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}% <---

\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus}{
\node[shape=circle split, 
draw,  minimum size=2*\pgfplotmarksize, inner sep=0pt,
]{};
}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus*}{
\node[shape=circle split, 
draw,   fill,  
minimum size=2*\pgfplotmarksize, inner sep=0pt,
]{};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
ticks=none,    
only marks, 
mark size=5.67pt
]
\addplot+[mark=oplus, mark options={fill=none}] coordinates { 
     (0.20,0.05) %
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)  
};

\addplot+[mark=oplus*, draw=brown, mark options={draw=brown, fill=purple!44}] coordinates { 
      (0.35,0.60)
};

\addplot+[red, mark=myominus] coordinates { 
      (0.05,0.50)
%      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
};

\addplot+[mark=myominus*,  draw=green, mark options={fill=yellow}] coordinates { 
      (0.10,0.15)
}; 
      
\fill[pink] (0,0) rectangle (0.95, 0.6);
\fill[cyan!55] (0,0.6) rectangle (0.95, 1.0);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**2. Old.**

```
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus}{
\node[inner sep=-1.4pt, circle, draw, fill=pink] {$-$};
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 

\tikzset{
markstyle/.style={inner sep=-1.4pt, circle, draw,   },
}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myominus}{
\node[markstyle, fill=pink] {$-$};
}
\pgfdeclareplotmark{myoplus}{
\node[markstyle, fill=cyan!55]{$+$};
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
only marks, 
]
\addplot+[mark=myominus] coordinates { 
     (0.20,0.05)
      (0.25,0.60)
      (0.55,0.40)
      (0.90, 0.85)  
};
\addplot+[mark=myoplus] coordinates { 
      (0.05,0.50)
      (0.10,0.15)
      (0.30,0.85)
      (0.45, 0.95)
      (0.60, 0.75)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```